# Is there a way to check multiple columns using "IN" condition in Redshift Spectrum?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I have a Redshift Spectrum table named as `customer_details_table` where the column `id` is not unique. I have another column `hierarchy` which is based on which record should be given priority if they have the same id. Here's an example:

[image]

Here, if we encounter the same id as `28846` multiple times, we will choose John as the one to be qualified, considering he has the maximum hierarchy.

I'm trying to create this `eligibility` column using a `group by` on `id` and then selecting the record corresponding to maximum `hierarchy`. Here's my SQL code:

```
SELECT *,
CASE WHEN (
     (id , hierarchy) IN 
            (SELECT id , max(hierarchy)
            FROM
              customer_details_table
            GROUP BY id
            )
) THEN 'Qualified' ELSE 'Disqualified' END as eligibility
FROM
  customer_details_table
```

Upon running this I get the following error:

```
SQL Error [500310] [XX000]: [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: This type of IN/NOT IN query is not supported yet;
```

The above code works fine when my table (`customer_details_table`) is a regular Redshift table, but fails when the same table is an external spectrum table. Can anyone please suggest a good solution/alternative to achieve the same logic in spectrum tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions to generate the `eligibility` column:

Basically you need to partition the rows by `id`, and rank by descending `hierarchy` within each group.

```
select
    *,
    case when row_number() over(partition by id order by hierarchy desc) = 1
        then 'Qualified' else 'Disqualified'
    end eligibility
from customer_details_table
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions:

```
select cdt.*
from (select cdt.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by hierarchy desc) as seqnum
      from customer_details_table cdt
     ) cdt
where seqnum = 1;
```